# "LIBSSH2 not found. Set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH if it is installed outside of the default search path." while building gem

Tags: macos, libssh2, libssl

I'm on macOS 11.6.1, and I'm trying to install [Rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) as a dependency of another tool, and while building it, I'm running into the following problem (note **missing** libssl, while openssl **is found**):

```
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rugged-1.2.0/ext/rugged
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20211029-46936-1d8xvnm.rb extconf.rb
checking for gmake... no
checking for make... yes
checking for cmake... yes
checking for pkg-config... yes
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2")
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIM
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIM - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIMESPEC
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIMESPEC - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_MTIME_NSEC
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_MTIME_NSEC - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_NSEC
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_NSEC - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WERROR_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WERROR_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Looking for futimens
-- Looking for futimens - found
-- Performing Test IS_WNO_ERROR_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WNO_ERROR_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WALL_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WALL_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WEXTRA_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WEXTRA_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WDOCUMENTATION_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WDOCUMENTATION_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WNO_DOCUMENTATION_DEPRECATED_SYNC_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WNO_DOCUMENTATION_DEPRECATED_SYNC_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WNO_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WNO_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WSTRICT_ALIASING_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WSTRICT_ALIASING_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WDECLARATION_AFTER_STATEMENT_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WDECLARATION_AFTER_STATEMENT_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WSHIFT_COUNT_OVERFLOW_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WSHIFT_COUNT_OVERFLOW_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WUNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WUNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WUNUSED_FUNCTION_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WUNUSED_FUNCTION_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WINT_CONVERSION_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WINT_CONVERSION_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WC11_EXTENSIONS_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WC11_EXTENSIONS_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WC99_C11_COMPAT_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WC99_C11_COMPAT_SUPPORTED - Failed
-- Performing Test IS_WFORMAT_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WFORMAT_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WFORMAT_SECURITY_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WFORMAT_SECURITY_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Checking prototype qsort_r for HAVE_QSORT_R_BSD
-- Checking prototype qsort_r for HAVE_QSORT_R_BSD - True
-- Checking prototype qsort_r for HAVE_QSORT_R_GNU
-- Checking prototype qsort_r for HAVE_QSORT_R_GNU - False
-- Looking for qsort_s
-- Looking for qsort_s - not found
-- Looking for clock_gettime in rt
-- Looking for clock_gettime in rt - not found
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib (found version "3.0.0")
-- Found Security /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework
-- Looking for SSLCreateContext in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework
-- Looking for SSLCreateContext in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework - found
-- Found CoreFoundation /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework
-- Could NOT find PCRE (missing: PCRE_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Looking for dirent.h
-- Looking for dirent.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for inttypes.h
-- Looking for inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Looking for windows.h
-- Looking for windows.h - not found
-- Looking for bcopy
-- Looking for bcopy - found
-- Looking for memmove
-- Looking for memmove - found
-- Looking for strerror
-- Looking for strerror - found
-- Looking for strtoll
-- Looking for strtoll - found
-- Looking for strtoq
-- Looking for strtoq - found
-- Looking for _strtoi64
-- Looking for _strtoi64 - not found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of long long
-- Check size of long long - done
-- Check size of unsigned long long
-- Check size of unsigned long long - done
-- Performing Test IS_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Performing Test IS_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_SUPPORTED - Success
-- http-parser version 2 was not found or disabled; using bundled 3rd-party sources.
-- Performing Test IS_WIMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_1_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test IS_WIMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_1_SUPPORTED - Failed
-- Found ZLIB: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd (found version "1.2.11")
-- Checking for module 'libssh2'
--   Package 'libssl', required by 'libssh2', not found
-- LIBSSH2 not found. Set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH if it is installed outside of the default search path.
-- Checking for module 'heimdal-gssapi'
--   No package 'heimdal-gssapi' found
-- Could NOT find GSSAPI (missing: GSSAPI_LIBRARIES)
-- Found GSS.framework /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework
-- Looking for iconv_open
-- Looking for iconv_open - not found
-- Found Iconv: -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/lib -liconv
-- Enabled features:
 * nanoseconds, whether to use sub-second file mtimes and ctimes
 * tracing, tracing support
 * futimens, futimens support
 * threadsafe, threadsafe support
 * HTTPS, using SecureTransport
 * SHA, using CollisionDetection
 * regex, using bundled PCRE
 * http-parser, http-parser support (bundled)
 * zlib, using system zlib
 * ntlmclient, NTLM authentication support for Unix
 * iconv, iconv encoding conversion support

-- Disabled features:
 * debugpool, debug pool allocator
 * debugalloc, debug strict allocators
 * debugopen, path validation in open
 * SSH, SSH transport support
 * SPNEGO, SPNEGO authentication support

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rugged-1.2.0/vendor/libgit2/build
 -- /usr/bin/make
checking for -lgit2... yes
checking for git2.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rugged-1.2.0/ext/rugged
make DESTDIR\= clean

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rugged-1.2.0/ext/rugged
make DESTDIR\=
compiling rugged.c
compiling rugged_allocator.c
compiling rugged_backend.c
compiling rugged_blame.c
compiling rugged_blob.c
compiling rugged_branch.c
compiling rugged_branch_collection.c
compiling rugged_commit.c
compiling rugged_config.c
compiling rugged_cred.c
compiling rugged_diff.c
compiling rugged_diff_delta.c
compiling rugged_diff_hunk.c
compiling rugged_diff_line.c
compiling rugged_index.c
compiling rugged_note.c
compiling rugged_object.c
compiling rugged_patch.c
compiling rugged_rebase.c
compiling rugged_reference.c
compiling rugged_reference_collection.c
compiling rugged_remote.c
compiling rugged_remote_collection.c
compiling rugged_repo.c
compiling rugged_revwalk.c
compiling rugged_settings.c
compiling rugged_signature.c
compiling rugged_submodule.c
compiling rugged_submodule_collection.c
compiling rugged_tag.c
compiling rugged_tag_collection.c
compiling rugged_tree.c
linking shared-object rugged/rugged.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.6.Internal.sdk/usr/local/lib'

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rugged-1.2.0/ext/rugged
make DESTDIR\= install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 rugged.bundle ./.gem.20211029-46936-hndxh9/rugged
```

My relevant env variables in `.zshrc`:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include"
export OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3
export OPENSSL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib
export OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib/
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"
```

I'm fairly new to macOS and need to get "SSH transport support" for Rugged to work with the other tool, so I'm not sure what else I should try. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a long shot, but there seems to be some resemblance to https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/556; perhaps running xcode-select --install is worth a try.

Comment: Tools are already installed: "xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates"